# Как переводить int в перечисление (enum class) с проверкой валидности результата?

Tags: c++

```
enum class Foo : int
{
    unknown = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3,
};

int main()
{    
    int i = 4;

    Foo foo = Foo::unknown;

    foo = static_cast<Foo>(i); // foo = 4 - не попадает в энум

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли способ перевод инт в перечисление с проверкой валидности результата?

Comment: Можно сделать его типизированным, как `enum class Foo: int`, тогда преобразование будет всегда валидным. Иначе получается хз что, так как значение 4 не попадает в диапазон.

Comment: @VTT, если типизировать, то всё равно foo = 4, что не верно, после каста надо вручную проверять принадлежность результата энуму

Comment: Нет, если типизировать как int, то 4 будет валидным значением. Видимо вы предполагаете, что валидные значения енумератора ограничиваются перечнем именованных значений в его объявлении.

Comment: @VTT, технически, понятно, не ограничиваются) но суть вопроса в касте с проверкой

Comment: преобразование тогда должно быть определено классом? Вопрос в накладных расходах. Я предпочитаю использовать перечисления только для статики (параметры шаблонов) или как списки масок (см. Qt), а не присваивать во время исполнения.

Comment: Ну тогда брать и проверять на попадание в диапазон "правильных" значений.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "валидностью результата"? Попадание в диапазон? Или попадание в одно из именованных значений?

Comment: @Ant, в одно из именованных значений.

Comment: В языке нет такого понятия валидности. Значение enum не обязано попадать в одно из именованных значений. Поэтому проверять придется явно ручками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если значения констант идут по порядку, и вы знаете имена первой и последней константы, то все легко:

```
if (i < int(Foo::unknown) && i > int(Foo::three)) { /* ошибка, i вне диапазона */ }
```

---

А вот в общем случае (для произвольных констант) это нельзя сделать автоматически средствами чистого С++.

Придется писать что вроде:

```
bool is_valid_foo(int x)
{
    return x == int(Foo::unknown) || x == int(Foo::one)   ||
           x == int(Foo::two)     || x == int(Foo::three);
}
```

Вручную делать это неудобно. Если отказаться от обычного синтаксиса определения `enum`ов и заменить его на макросы, то такие функции можно генерировать автоматически вместе с самим `enum`ом используя [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) или [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Другой вариант: написать какой-нибудь скрипт, который будет сам получать список констант из объявления `enum`а (через [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) или что-то подобное), а потом генерировать соответствующую функцию.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите **enum** объекту присвоить НЕ родное значение, вижу только использование личной функции с контролем диапазонов.

```
enum class Foo : int
{
    invalid = -1 ,
    unknown = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3,

};

Foo & Set(Foo & f, int i)
{
    if((i < static_cast<int>(Foo::unknown)) or (static_cast<int>(Foo::three) < i))
    {
        f = Foo::invalid;
    }
    else
    {
        f = static_cast<Foo>(i);
    }
    return f;
}

int main()
{    
    int i = 4;

    Foo foo = Foo::unknown;

    foo = static_cast<Foo>(i); // использовать НЕ надо !

    Set(foo, i) ; // правильно

    return 0;
}
```

Можно контролировать, что значение равно **invalid** или вызывать исключение, на ваш вкус.